# php session_set_cookie_params and session_name query

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I am new to php. I have some silly php session doubts below:

```
session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/folder1');
session_name('MYSITE_SID');
```

**Q1)** Above `/folder1` means what? will cookie store under '/folder1'? so does cookie looks visible under folder1?

We have a websites like :

```
www.mysite.com/folder1
www.mysite.com/folder2
```

**Q2)** Can I keep same `session_name` for above 2 folders of same website? or should keep different session names?

**Note:** If user already logged in  `'www.mysite.com/folder1`', he should NOT be able to get loggedin  automatically in `www.mysite.com/folder2`

Sorry for stupid queries. but please I wanna learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *path* parameter in `session_set_cookie_params` makes the server send a cookie header only when that *path* exists in the requested resource.Eg:

`Set-Cookie: name=Nicholas; path=/blog`

In this example, the path option would match /blog, /blogroll, etc.; anything that begins with /blog is valid.  So it's not about cookie visibility through out your site but more of when the cookie will be set by the server. Read [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/) for more info.

For your second question, you should use the same session name through out your site as I don't see a practical reason why you would need to change it IMHO. Finally, restricting parts of your site to users has more to do with [AAA](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=authorization%20authentication%20and%20accounting) (Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting) than with sessions.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please also tell me where went wrong here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345780/mysite-immediately-getting-logged-out-for-2nd-request?noredirect=1#comment52565630_32345780