# MySIte immediately getting logged out for 2nd request

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I am new to php. I am facing problem with sessions. I mean, after I get logged in and I click on any link in the website , its immediately getting logged out. Not sure why.

In chrome console: I entered as : document.cookie , it showing me "", then I got to understand that cookie is somehow getting deleted immediately  or some other issue.

This problem exists for below 2 websites.

We have a websites like :

```
www.mysite.site1.com/folder1
www.mysite.site2.com/folder2
```

**Below is my code of MySite.com/folder1**

```
   function MySession() {
      $params = session_get_cookie_params();
      session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/v/folder1');
      session_start();
   }

   function clear()
   {
      $_SESSION=array();
      session_destroy();
   }
```

**Below is my code of MySite.com/folder2**

```
 function MySession() {
      $params = session_get_cookie_params();
      session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/v/folder2');
      session_start();
   }

   function clear()
   {
      $_SESSION=array();
      session_destroy();
   }
```

Comment: [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) ... by setting a path for the session cookie you limiting what urls it is transfered to.

Comment: @Orangepill How path value effects mysite?  I am sorry i didn't, Could you please tell me what I have to change in my code?

Comment: use session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/');
if you want to use differ-differ session for folder1 and folder2 you can create virtual host and setup it.

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav Whats wrong if I use as :  session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/v/folder2');  ??

Comment: for chrome go to your browser inspect Element resource cookies in cookies you get a path column and domain which is very important to maintain session.
giving a path for cookies you are setting limitation of cookies which is only access for that folder.

Comment: in PHP if your are setting `$_SESSION['VALUE']` then you need to start `session_start()` in every page and make sure website base url shouldn't change, if this happens then you'll logged out.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU I just edited my domain names above, previously entered wrong. here is one:  www.mysite.site1.com/folder1

Now please tell me what really I have to change..?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the domain for cookies in session_set_cookie_params() only affects the domain used for the session cookie .

So to make all your cookies be available across all sub-domains of your site you need to set your cookies on root domain.

when setting the path that the cookie is valid for, always remember to have that trailing '/'.

CORRECT:

```
session_set_cookie_params (0, '/yourpath/');
```

INCORRECT:

```
session_set_cookie_params (0, '/yourpath');
```

Comment: I just edited my domain names above, previously entered wrong. here is one:  www.mysite.site1.com/folder1

Now please tell me what really I have to change..?

I even tried 'trailer' slash as you said, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

`mysite.site1.com` is your base url.

when you switched from `www.mysite.site1.com/folder1` 
to 
`www.mysite.site2.com/folder2`

you'll surely be logged out.

Comment: Sorry to ask like this, where do I set this base url? and how? and how about if I try using session_name('FOLDER1'); for www.mysite.site1.com/folder1  and similar way for other folder too..

Comment: using codeigniter will handle all these things for you. session urls security encryption etc. since you are not using let me tell you simple solution

Comment: [set site base url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481629/how-do-i-set-base-url-for-all-pages-of-my-website)

Comment: `<?php
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.mysite.site1.com/');`
and in projects use it like this.
`BASE_URL."folder1"` will print `www.mysite.site1.com/folder1`

Comment: Just for the sake of 1 issue, I can think its not advisable to go with some framework especially for the already existing running project..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88557/discussion-between-lukyboy-ku-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am able to find out answer for my query:

since in my case I have 2 folders ie., www.mysite.com/folder1 && www.mysite.com/folder2 , then we MUST keep `session_name('folder1') for 'folder1'`  and `session_name('folder2') for 'folder2'` , otherwise both folders share the same session ID and so user gets logged in automatically in folder2 (assuming if he already got loggedin folder1)

```
 function Session() {
      session_name('FOLDER_SID');
      session_start();
   }
```

Regarding more info about session_name, here:  `http://stackoverflow.com/a/7551430/4956785`